# Binding to multiple properties: should I use IMultiValueConverter or a calculated property?

Tags: wpf

I have an object with two properties, say A and B. I want to bind a control in my UI to A*B. I have found two ways of doing this, but neither pleases me. The first is to add a calculated property to my object, say C, that returns A*B. It is read-only and therefore I have to raise PropertyChanged (of C) in the setters of both A and B.

The second is to implement IMultiValueConverter in my code behind in conjunction with a MultiBinding in my XAML. But that seems like a lot of work, especially if I need to do this for many controls in my UI.

Which of these two is the better option, or is there a different best practice way?

Comment: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/oaph/

Comment: If `typeof(AB)` is `String`, there is `Multibinding` and `Stringformat`. If not, could you give a more precice use case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing wrong with calling PropertyChanged ( nameof ( C ) ) in A & B properties provided your viewmodel is relatively small and readable.

As a matter of preference, if the calculated property has a "business" meaning, I'll try to keep it in the viewmodel.

If there's a real necessity to keep all your viewmodel properties "pure", you could do something like this:

```
class ABCViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ABCViewModel ( )
    {
        PropertyChanged += ( sender, e ) =>
        {
            if (    e.PropertyName == nameof ( A )
                 || e.PropertyName == nameof ( B ) )
            {
                C = A + B;
            }
        };
    }

    public int A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set
        {
            _a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( );
        }
    }
    private int _a;

    public int B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set
        {
            _b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( );
        }
    }
    private int _b;

    public int C
    {
        get { return _c; }
        private set
        {
            _c = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( );
        }
    }
    private int _c;
}
```